# What do teal/light blue bombs do?

Tags: super-bomberman-r

In Super Bomberman R online play I've gotten a power up which turns bombs teal/light blue.

What is the difference between these light blue bombs and normal bombs?

Comment: Any chance of a screenshot?

Comment: Since this was already bumped to the main page.. It's worth noting that these types of bombs were more distinct in previous Bomberman games as they actually looked like they were made out of jelly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/204231-super-bomberman-r/75068334), it looks like it turns your bombs bouncy:

> It makes your bombs slippery and bouncy.
>
> When you kick them, they slide back and forth, and when you throw or punch them they jump around.